The gif embedded into my link is not showing on discord
I'm trying to make it then if you middle click a discord gif it would direct you to my website but discord is not getting the embed in my link and only shows the link plain
The code on the website:
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="dont-middle-click.gif">
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.other">
    <?php
        $actual_link = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        if (!str_contains($actual_link, 'https')) {
            header("Location: https://yumd.42web.io");
            die();
        }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Why did you middle click the gif</p>
</body>
</html>

This is the result i get:
A message on discord of a link
I expected the link to disappear and only show the "dont-middle-click.gif"

Try and give an absolute URL for og:image, instead of a relative one.

@CBroe I tried replacing the gif with the original link i got it from tenor and it still wouldn't work

That URL redirects me to https://tenor.com/view/dont-middle-click-gif-444441891819062867 - which is not a GIF, but an HTML document. It might be that this returns a GIF under specific conditions - but you can't know if these conditions will be met, when discord's scraping mechanism requests this URL. You should really rather host the image yourself, than use external services, to avoid this kind of potential issue.

@CBroe The link I sent is a gif link but it redirects you to a html I hyperlinked it but this is the link I sent https://tenor.com/GZIaT4pP67.gif and I downloaded the gif and added to the server that’s why I’m not using a link

And what is your point now? "but it redirects you to a html" - yes, and it might do the same for discord. And discord is not going to use an HTML document as the preview image.

@CBroe then what I’m I supposed to do I tried to download the gif and put it in the server then name it on the code and that’s not working

OG meta data usually gets cached, so it might not even see any modifications you are making right now. I don't know if discord has any tool to invalidate that cache. Try and share a different URL that delivers this HTML content, one discord doesn't know about yet, and see if that changes things. And I also don't know if discord support animated OG images to begin with.

@CBroe Should i make a new html file and send it in discord with the updated code

You need a different URL to share (to prevent discord from accessing already cached OG meta data for a URL it already knows); where the content that URL returns comes from (static file, dynamic script), isn't really relevant.
